# There are i can not update language variable value when i call alert dialog and i select one language that bot update in context screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
RichText(
text: TextSpan(
style: defaultStyle,
children: [
TextSpan(
text: 'Language',
recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
..onTap = () {
showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return AlertDialog(
title: Text('Language List'),
content: Container(

```
                                                  height: 200.0, // Change as per your requirement
                                                  width: 200.0, // Change as per your requirement
                                                  child:ListView.builder(
                                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                                      itemCount: languages.length,
                                                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                                        return ListTile(
                                                          title: Text(languages[index],
                                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                letterSpacing: 1.0
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          onTap: () {
                                                            String lan = languages[index];
                                                            Navigator.of(context).pop({languages[index]});
                                                            Phoenix.rebirth(context);
                                                            print(language);
                                                            setState((){

                                                              language = lan;
                                                              print(language);
                                                            });

                                                          },
                                                        );
                                                      }
                                                  ))
                                            );
                                          });
                                    }),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      Text('$language')

                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly you need to update something using setState in AlertDialog. For that, you need to make the AlertDialog stateful.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text(contentText),
          actions: <Widget>[
           
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```